# MIPS/MARS using symbols in a directive?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to create an array of pointers to strings, but it's not behaving as expected. The array has the contents of the strings, not the addresses. Here's the source code:

```
    showhelp:
        .data
    help1:  .asciiz "\nHELP FOR HW4_2b\n"
    help2:  .asciiz "Purpose: Displays the output from a one-bit full adder with inputs provided on the command line.\n"
    help3:  .asciiz "HW4_2b c a b\n"
    help4:  .asciiz "c\t\tThe carry in bit: 0|1\n"
    help5:  .asciiz "a\t\tOne of the bits to be added: 0|1\n"
    help6:  .asciiz "c\t\tThe other bit to be added: 0|1\n"
    helpar: .word help1, help2, help3, help4, help6
    helpsiz:.word 6
            .text
            lw          $t0, helpsiz    # load size of help array
            lw          $t1, helpar     # load address of address of first help string
    nxthlp: la          $a0, ($t1)      # specify string to print
            li          $v0, 4          # specify print string 
            syscall                     # print it
            addi        $t1, $t1, 4     # increment pointer to next string
            subi        $t0, $t0, 1     # decrement counter
            bgtz        $t0, nxthlp     # if not last string loop

            jr $ra          # return
```

When this runs, this is the output:

```
    HELP FOR HW4_2b
    P FOR HW4_2b
    R HW4_2b
    4_2b

    rpose: Displays the output from a one-bit full adder with inputs provided on the command line.
```

As you can see, the helpar: contains all the strings concatenated, rather than the addresses. Also, the indirect addressing in the "la $a0, ($t1)" is loading the contents of $t1, rather than the contents at the address contained in $t1.

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
        lw          $t0, helpsiz
        lw          $t1, helpar     # load address of 1st string
nxthlp: la          $a0, ($t1)      # NOT SURE IF THIS IS EVEN VALID
        li          $v0, 4
        syscall
        addi        $t1, $t1, 4     # skip 4 chars in string; must be unsigned add!
        subi        $t0, $t0, 1
        bgtz        $t0, nxthlp
```

Here's what you should do instead:

```
    lw      $t0, helpsiz
    la      $t1, helpar # t1 points to element 0 of helpar
nxthlp:
    lw      $a0, 0($t1) # fetch element of helpar that t1 points to
    li      $v0, 4
    syscall
    addu    $t1, $t1, 4 # t1 points to next element of helpar
    subi    $t0, $t0, 1
    bgtz    $t0, nxthlp
```